# Is it possible to output message keys in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, translation, symfony5

I have a Symfony 5 website that uses Twig templates containing messages translated with

```
{% trans %}some.message.key{% endtrans %}
```

Is there a way to have Symfony output the message key itself instead of the translation? This can be helpful during development and translation work.

To demonstrate what I want, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page?uselang=qqx, which shows such behavior in the MediaWiki software.

Comment: Basically, whenever a translation is missing Symfony will output the key during development by default. You can also retrieve a list of missing translations and places where a fallback was used. So, if I understand correctly, all you need to do is set an invalid/untranslated locale and then the translator will output the key instead of the translation (in the dev-environment). Does that help?